# How to order an array of objects by value? usi

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects such as

```
const myArrayOfColors = [
  { color: "red", number: 123 },
  { color: "red", number: 12 },
  { color: "green", number: 6 },
  { color: "blue", number: 7 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
  { color: "green", number: 74 },
  { color: "blue", number: 41 },
  { color: "purple", number: 74 },
];
```

and I have an array of strings that I have to use as an order reference:

```
myOrder = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green"];
```

so I have to sort my objects array in order to comply with my order reference. I should have an output like this:

```
const myArrayOfColors = [
  { color: "red", number: 123 },
  { color: "blue", number: 7 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
  { color: "green", number: 6 },
  { color: "red", number: 12 },
  { color: "blue", number: 41 },
  { color: "purple", number: 74 },
  { color: "green", number: 74 },
];
```

Comment: What if there isn't enough elements to 'repeat' it? How do you know which color goes first (they have different numbers, signifying that they are each unique)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is best way, You can try this. So basically we run through the `myArrayOfColors` and then loop the `order` to find the order element, push it in result, then after Delete the item from main source `(myArrayOfColors)`. Of course think about `Time Complexity (assuming n³)` here. (It's big )

```js
const myArrayOfColors = [
  {color: 'red', number: 123},
  {color: 'red',  number: 12},
  {color:'green', number: 6},
  {color: 'blue', number: 7},
  {color:'purple', number:54},
  {color: 'green', number: 74},
  {color:'blue', number:41},
  {color: 'purple', number: 74},
]

const order = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green']
const result = []

while(myArrayOfColors.length) {
 for (const o of order) {
    const colorIndex = myArrayOfColors.findIndex(e => e.color === o)
    if (colorIndex > -1) {
      result.push(myArrayOfColors[colorIndex])
      myArrayOfColors.splice(colorIndex, 1)
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think time complexity is `n³` right, can anyone confirm?

Comment: You can do ```result.push(...myArrayOfColors.splice(colorIndex, 1))```.

Answer (score 0):

Will work even for uneven groups that cannot be repeated.

I've added `{color:'green',number:74}` and `{color:'red',number:74}` to the end of `myArrayOfColors`:

```js
const myArrayOfColors=[{color:'red',number:123},{color:'red',number:12},{color:'green',number:6},{color:'blue',number:7},{color:'purple',number:54},{color:'green',number:74},{color:'blue',number:41},{color:'purple',number:74},{color:'green',number:74}, {color:'red',number:74}]
const myOrder = ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green']

const res = []
let maxIterations = myArrayOfColors.length - myOrder.length

while (maxIterations--) {
  myOrder.forEach(e => {
    const c = myArrayOfColors.find(x => x.color === e) ?? {}
    c.color && res.push({...c})
    c.color = "-"
  })
}

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to make groups of unique elements, sorted according to a colors array:

```js
function* createdOrderedGroups(items, colors) {
  items = [...items]
  let colorIndex = 0;
  while (items.length) {
    const index = items.findIndex(item => item.color === colors[colorIndex])
    if (index === -1) {
      throw new Error('Each color did not have the same number of assosiated items.');
    }
    yield items[index]
    items.splice(index, 1);

    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length
  }
}

const myArrayOfColors = [
  {color: 'red', number: 123},
  {color: 'red',  number: 12},
  {color:'green', number: 6},
  {color: 'blue', number: 7},
  {color:'purple', number:54},
  {color: 'green', number: 74},
  {color:'blue', number:41},
  {color: 'purple', number: 74},
]

console.log([...createdOrderedGroups(myArrayOfColors, ['red', 'blue', 'purple', 'green'])])
```

Basically, we gradually remove items from the input array every time we find one with the color we're looking for, until there are no items left. We know which color we're looking for, by using a `colorIndex` variable, which starts at 0, and increments with each iteration until we get to the length of the color array, then it restarts at 0.

I'm using a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) here (the function* and yield stuff), but if that's new to you, you can instead just build a results array and return that whole array.

This solution will yield the first occurrence of each color from the input array, then it will yield the next occurrence it finds, and so forth, so the last item that has a color "red" will be one of the last elements yielded.

Answer (score 0):

- You can easily achieve this result using first create a `dict` that contains the `color` and its `number` in the respective array.
- calculate the `max` number of elements in respective `color`.
- Now we know the max elements in an array, so we can loop over up to `max` and get `color` and its number from `dict` and store in the `result` array.`

```js
const myArrayOfColors = [
  { color: "red", number: 123 },
  { color: "red", number: 12 },
  { color: "green", number: 6 },
  { color: "blue", number: 7 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
  { color: "green", number: 74 },
  { color: "blue", number: 41 },
  { color: "purple", number: 74 },
  { color: "purple", number: 94 },
];

const myOrder = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green"];
let max = 0;
const dict = myArrayOfColors.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { color, number } = curr;
  if (acc[color]) acc[color].push(number);
  else acc[color] = [number];

  max = Math.max(max, acc[color].length);
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
  myOrder.forEach((orderKey) => {
    const { [i]: val } = dict[orderKey];
    if (val) result.push({ color: orderKey, number: val });
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

### Above snippet can also cover the case if any `color` repeat more than in `myArrayOfColors`, e.g `purple` repeat more than any color in array

```
const myArrayOfColors = [
  { color: "red", number: 123 },
  { color: "red", number: 12 },
  { color: "green", number: 6 },
  { color: "blue", number: 7 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
  { color: "green", number: 74 },
  { color: "blue", number: 41 },
  { color: "purple", number: 74 },
  { color: "purple", number: 94 },
  { color: "purple", number: 84 },
  { color: "purple", number: 64 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

First build separate lists of the entries for each color, then use a custom comparator function for [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
const myArrayOfColors = [
  { color: "red", number: 123 },
  { color: "red", number: 12 },
  { color: "green", number: 6 },
  { color: "blue", number: 7 },
  { color: "purple", number: 54 },
  { color: "green", number: 74 },
  { color: "blue", number: 41 },
  { color: "purple", number: 74 },
];

myOrder = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green"];

myArraysPerColor = {};
for(const color of myOrder) {
  myArraysPerColor[color] = myArrayOfColors.filter(v=>v.color===color);
}

myArrayOfColors.sort((a,b) => 
  myArraysPerColor[a.color].indexOf(a)-myArraysPerColor[b.color].indexOf(b) ||
    myOrder.indexOf(a.color)-myOrder.indexOf(b.color)
);


console.log(myArrayOfColors);
```